# Are there two distinctly separate definitions for the Optional Stopping Theorem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I have been reading a book called Stochastic Calculus by Steele. Inside, they have a theorem they state as the "Optional Stopping Time Theorem":

If $M_n$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n$, then the stopped process $M_{n \wedge \tau}$ is also a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n$.

However, on Wikipedia, [Optional Stopping Theorem - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) they state the optional stopping theorem in terms of three separate sufficient statements. At first glance, these two don't look the same. Is there a chance they are talking about the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the Optional Stopping Theorem (OST). That is the Optional Stopping *Time* Theorem. In Williams' Probability with Martingales, such statement (which doesn't have the cool name) comes before the OST:

---

p. 99

[image]

---

p. 100

[image]